# Why use the function of form_valid to add created by logic?

Tags: django, django-views

I was able to configure creating a form which automatically uses the logged in user to populate the author/created-by field. The way I understood form_valid is *if form is valid*, a redirect is called to the success_url. My question is why put the logic *(form.instance.created_by=self.request.user)* inside of form_valid. I want to understand why I would want to do it. You can see the code below:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

For background purposes, I used a generic view found below:

```
class PostQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'post_question.html'
    fields = [
        'subject',
        'description',
    ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('questions:home')
```

Current environment is Django 3.0.3 and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_valid` is called by the view when a form has been entered checked, and determined to have valid input, right before the form's created (or updated) instance is saved.

You can use `form_valid` to do some additional changes to the saved object, that the form itself cannot derive, in this case, adding the user who posted the Question.

You wouldn't want the user to manually add their username to the form.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Therefore any logic related to saving an object can be placed her. Can you give some changes you can possible do within form_valid aside from automatically assigning the user?

Comment: You can do any changes you want, but my advice is to keep it to changes you wouldn't normally be able to do in the `form.save()`, or `model.save()` method.

In this case, setting the user can not be done on a lower level, since the form and model have no reference to `request`, and consequently, no way to determine the current user.

Answer (score 0):

request.user is simply a method to get the username of logged in user. Your line instance created by simply means that it is just to know which user submitted the form